# Replace numerical values in a data.frame according to a column of values

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that looks like:

> ```
> DF   
> col1      col2     col3      col4      
> Name_1     0.3    Sample1     NA     
> Name_2     0.2    Sample2     NA      
> Name_3     0.9    Sample3     1   
> Name_4     0.4    Sample4     NA          
> Name_5     0.2    Sample5     2
> ```

i would like to replace the numerical values in col2 with 0 when in col4  there's a number. 
In other words the desired output will be:

> ```
> DF   
> col1      col2     col3      col4      
> Name_1     0.3    Sample1     NA     
> Name_2     0.2    Sample2     NA      
> Name_3     0      Sample3     1   
> Name_4     0.4    Sample4     NA          
> Name_5     0      Sample5     2
> ```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mattrition's answer is best, but here's an `ifelse` method

```
> DF$col2 <- ifelse(!is.na(DF$col4), 0, DF$col2) 
> DF
##     col1 col2    col3 col4
## 1 Name_1  0.3 Sample1   NA
## 2 Name_2  0.2 Sample2   NA
## 3 Name_3  0.0 Sample3    1
## 4 Name_4  0.4 Sample4   NA
## 5 Name_5  0.0 Sample5    2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the negation of the output from `is.na` to find where `col4` is not `NA`.

```
where.notNA <- !is.na(DF$col4)
```

This logical vector can be used to select the rows in col2 that you want to assign to 0:

```
DF$col2[where.notNA] <- 0
```

So, as a one-liner:

```
DF$col2[!is.na(DF$col4)] <- 0
```